# Why do I have to put an integer twice for my Scanner input to work?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a simple program where you can put integers in, and it will tell you if it increased or decreased from the previous integer input. But when I run the code, I have to put an integer value twice, but I only want it put once.

The input and output should look like (numbers typed by me, words output by the program):

```
Starting...
5
Increasing
4
Decreasing
6
Increasing
```

etc. etc.

But instead it looks like:

```
Starting...
5
5
Increasing
Input Number:
1
2
Not Increasing
```

etc. etc.

This is my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prob1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting...");
        int input;
        int previousInput = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!(scan.nextInt() <= 0)) {
            input = scan.nextInt();
            if (input > previousInput) {
                System.out.println("Increasing");
                previousInput = input;

            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Increasing");
                previousInput = input;
            }
            System.out.println("Input Number:");
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Why does this problem occur, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to think about the code carefully, a step at a time. Where it says `while (!(scan.nextInt() <= 0)) {`, what do you expect that to do? Where it says `input = scan.nextInt();`, what do you expect that to do? Between those two lines of code, how many times do you see the code `scan.nextInt()`? When you run the code, how many times do you have to type the number? Do you see a correlation?

Comment: The way it's written, there's a `scan.nextInt()` in the `while` statement, so that runs first, and then if the rest of the condition is true (so, if `!(scan.nextInt() <= 0)` returns "true") the next line is one more `scan.nextInt()`. Each pass through the loop, the same thing will happen – the `while` condition, then one more inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop behavior you are describing is:

- read a numeric input value
- do something with it (print a message)
- if the loop value meets a condition (input is 0 or less), exit the loop
- otherwise, repeat

Here's a "do-while" loop that reads like those steps above:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int input;
do {
    input = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("input: " + input);
} while (input > 0);
System.out.println("done");
```

And here's input+output, first entering "1", then entering "0":

```
1
input: 1
0
input: 0
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`while (!(scan.nextInt() <= 0)) {` takes an int and then `input = scan.nextInt();` takes another one. You need to change the while loop to use `input`.

Answer (score 0):

modified based on your code

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting...");
        int input;
        int previousInput = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Input Number:");
            input = scan.nextInt();
            if (input <= 0) {
                System.out.println("app shut down");
                break;
            }
            if (input > previousInput) {
                System.out.println("Increasing");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Increasing");
            }
            previousInput = input;
        }
        scan.close();
    }
```